# Resetear el estado de un Activity, evitar que al reabrirlo vuelva aparecer la informacion

Tags: android

La cuestion es, tengo un `Activity` con lista de restaurantes
al darle click a un restaurante del RecyclerView , me lleva a un activity
de descripción y Menu, al darle click al Activity Carrito de Compras,
se muestra en un RecyclerView la factura , el problema viene, cuando retrocedo y vuelvo al Al menu principal de la lista de Restaurantes y entro hasta el carrito desde un restaurante diferente, el estado del Activity del Carrito de Compras sigue como antes, si no le mando nueva Informacion, Y si le mando nueva Informacion el RecyclerView sigue en el mismo estado.

Intente terminando la actividad cada que se salga del Activity pero no funciona. ¿Ideas?

```
public void AbrirCarrito(View view) {
    Intent PanierIntent = new Intent(this, PanierActivity.class);
    PanierIntent.putExtra("clientes", (Serializable) listaCliente);
    startActivity(PanierIntent);
}
```

ActivityCarrito

```
 public class PanierActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DateFormat formatoHora = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    Calendar hora = Calendar.getInstance();
    CustomFontButton botonHora;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter_Carrito mRecyclerViewAdapterCarrito;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private List<Cliente> listaCliente = new ArrayList<>();

    CustomFontTextView tvTotalCommande;
    CustomFontTextView tvRemises;
    CustomFontTextView tvTotalRegler;

    double totalCommande;
    double totalDescuento;
    double remises;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_panier);

        remises=getIntent().getIntExtra("descuento",0);

        tvTotalCommande = (CustomFontTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalCommande);
        tvRemises = (CustomFontTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRemises);
        tvTotalRegler = (CustomFontTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalRegler);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvCarrito);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listaCliente= (List<Cliente>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("clientes");
        mRecyclerViewAdapterCarrito = new RecyclerViewAdapter_Carrito(this, listaCliente);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapterCarrito);

        botonHora = (CustomFontButton) findViewById(R.id.botonHora);
        obtenerHora();

        for(int x=0;x<listaCliente.size();x++){
            totalCommande=totalCommande+listaCliente.get(x).getTotalCliente();
        }
        for(int x=0;x<listaCliente.size();x++){
            totalDescuento=totalDescuento+listaCliente.get(x).getTotalDescuento();
        }

        String prueba= String.valueOf(totalCommande);
        String prueba2=String.valueOf(totalDescuento);

        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(prueba);
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(prueba2);

        a=a.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        b=b.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);


        tvTotalCommande.setText(String.valueOf(a)+"€");
        tvTotalRegler.setText(String.valueOf(b)+"€");




        tvRemises.setText(String.valueOf((a.subtract(b))+"€"));
    }

    private void obtenerHora(){
        botonHora.setText(formatoHora.format(hora.getTime()));
    }

    public void actualizarHora(View view){
        new TimePickerDialog(this,t,hora.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),hora.get(Calendar.MINUTE),true).show();
    }

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            hora.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
            hora.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
            obtenerHora();
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Hola, podrias agregar el codigo que estas utilizando?

Comment: @sioesi Listo, el metodo del boton con el que se abre el carrito y el Activity del Carrito. Gracias.

Comment: Entonces si yo agrego al carrito Por ejemplo un producto 1 del restaurant 1 y luego agrego producto 2 del restaurant 2 no se deberian ver ambos productos, solo los pedidos que correspondan al restaurant?

Comment: @sioesi exacto, te sales del restaurant , porque lo que aparezca en el carrito, es solo para pagar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final , el problema no era en el Activity Carrito , sino , en el Activity
que abria este , debi pasarles el codigo completo, pero es demasiado grande para pasarlo, la lista que paso a Carrito es estatica , lo cual que creo que ocasionaba que los valores de la lista jamas se perdieran al cambiarde Activity , agrege un onBackPressed con el codigo para limpiar la lista.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        listaCliente.clear();

    }
```

Gracias por ayudarme a pensar.

Comment: A veces yo recurro a boli y papel en determinar el flujo de la interfaz, es cuando realmente te viene la cabeza, cosas a tener en cuenta etc..

Comment: Gracias, empezare hacerlo , nada como el papel. @Webserveis